# Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I got this error:

> ```
> Caused by: PDOException
> invalid data source name
> in C:\wamp64\www\quickcar\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 686
> ```

This is the `main-local.php`:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'quickcar',
            'username' => 'quickcar',
            'password' => 'quickcar',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],

        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

`PDO` support multiple database vendor so u need to tell which database to connect in order.

> try this one

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=quickcar',
        'username' => 'quickcar',
        'password' => 'quickcar',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

if you are using  different port on mysql then do like this

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3307;dbname=quickcar'
```